# Confirmar transacción o utilizar rollback en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Un pregunta, resulta que estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL, el cual tiene como objetivo, insertar valores en tres distintas tablas, es de suma importancia que los tres valores se inserten al mismo tiempo, he leido que en tablas innodb, se puede mediante rollback cancelar todas las insercciones si alguna falla por cuestiones de caida del servidor, etc, el problema es que no encuentro la forma correcta de implementarlo en mi procedimiento. Espero me puedan apoyar. Muchas gracias. A continuación mi código de muestra.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insertar` (parametro varchar(10))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `bd`.`tabla1` (`campo`) VALUES (parametro);
INSERT INTO `bd`.`tabla2` (`campo`) VALUES (parametro);
INSERT INTO `bd`.`tabla3` (`campo`) VALUES (parametro);
/*Aquí no encuentro la forma de comprobar que se hayan realizado todos querys, en su caso hacer commit o rollback*/
END
```

Comment: Si lo quieres hacer desde un procedimiento almacenado, como parece ser, [revisa este tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx) donde se explica con todo detalle el funcionamiento de las transacciones con un ejemplo completo parecido a lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Transacción en MySQL Procedimiento almacenado**

Para realizar el ROLLBACK en MySQL Stored Procedure, debemos declarar el manejador de salida en el procedimiento almacenado. Hay dos tipos de controladores que podemos tener en MySQL Stored Procedure.

```
sqlexception
sqlwarning
```

**sqlexception** se ejecutará cuando se produzca algún error durante la ejecución de la consulta y **sqlwarning** se ejecutará cuando se produzca una advertencia en MySQL Stored Procedure. Veamos cómo podemos tener esos bloqueos en el Procedimiento almacenado.

Con tu codigo quedaria algo como:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `insertar` (parametro varchar(10))

BEGIN

DECLARE manejador de salida para sqlexception
  BEGIN
    -- ERROR
  ROLLBACK;
END;

DECLARE manejador de salida para sqlwarning
 BEGIN
    -- WARNING
 ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO `bd`.`tabla1` (`campo`) VALUES (parametro);
INSERT INTO `bd`.`tabla2` (`campo`) VALUES (parametro);
INSERT INTO `bd`.`tabla3` (`campo`) VALUES (parametro);

COMMIT;
END
$$
```

Comment: perdón la ignorancia, en donde pusiste "DECLARE manejador de salida para sqlexception" que código debe llevar?

Comment: hay tienes que colocar o setear el valor de la variable de salida indicando el error y puedes colocar tambien un insert a una tabla donde manejes los errores como una especie de bitacora de errores, luego viene el rollback qu quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguien mas pasa por lo mismo un ejemplo de uso de handler

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    SELECT 'An error has occurred, operation rollbacked and the stored procedure was terminated';
END;
```